# Drawing confidence regions around a multimodal bivariate kernel density plot

Tags: confidence-interval, joint-distribution, bivariate, kernel-smoothing

The following plot gives a bivariate kernel density plot (made with `kde2d` in `MASS`) of a deterministic functional evaluated at 500 posterior draws of 2 fitted models -- $Z = F(\hat{f}_1,\hat{f}_2)$, where $Z_i = [x_i,y_i]$.

```
load('dd')
library(MASS)
image(dd)
```

Data is here:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6z8x8cyluu5cu3/dd?dl=0

[image]

I want to draw regions that cover $Z$ with $1-\alpha$ probability, and I want them to include all (in this case both) optima, and to not necessarily cover the valley between them.  Intuitively, I'm imagining something that starts at the maxima and then goes down to some floor level at which 5% of the density can be found.

What is a principled way of doing this and how could I implement it in R?

EDIT:

Nevermind:  as soon as I formulated the question, the answer occured to me:

```
z = dd$z/sum(dd$z)#Normalize to 1
l = sort(z)[sum(cumsum(sort(z))<.05)]#this is the maximum density, below which all represent less than at 5%
contour(z,level=l,add=TRUE,lty=2,labels='')#This plots that "bathtub ring"
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but your solution doesn't seem right. What you're getting with your solution is the region where your estimated density is above 5% of your maximum estimated density. What you asked for is a 95% confidence region.

You can do this with the `hdrcde` package in R.

I can't do it with your data, as the `hdrcde` package seems to need the raw data too, but here's an example with a sample from a bi-modal multivariate normal distribution.

```
library(mvtnorm)
x <- rbind(rmvnorm(400, c(0, 0), sigma = diag(c(1, 1))),
           rmvnorm(600, c(5, 5), sigma = diag(c(1, 1))))
plot(x)
```

[image: Sample from distribution]

```
library(hdrcde)
o <- hdr.2d(x[, 1], x[, 2], prob = c(0.01, 0.05, 0.5))
plot(o)
legend("topleft", legend = o$alpha, title = "Confidence levels",
fill = gray((length(o$alpha):1)/(length(o$alpha)+1)))
```

[image: Confidence bounds from density estimate]